# Convert smalldatetime datatype to string. "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" error

Tags: c#, datetime

In my database I've got smalldate data type which look like this: "2014-09-01 19:00:00".

I am trying convert this string to date:

```
DateTime data2 = DateTime.ParseExact(obiekt.PelnaData, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I have tried this:

```
string query = "Select *, Convert(nvarchar, DataMeczu, 104) as formatData, Convert(nvarchar, DataMeczu, 114) as formatData2, Convert(nvarchar, DataMeczu, 120) as formatData3 From MyTable Where MyVar = @MyVar";

SqlDataReader rdr = com.ExecuteReader();
while(rdr.Read())
{
    TerminarzeLigaModel terminarz = new TerminarzeLigaModel();
    terminarz.PelnaData = rdr["formatData3"].ToString();

    or this version:

    string dataA = rdr["formatData"].ToString();
    string dataB = rdr["formatData2"].ToString();
    terminarz.PelnaData = dataA + " " + dataB; 
}
```

but every time I receive this error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime". I dont know what I am doing wrong. If I paste the date from the database into a variable:

```
string dataExample = "2014-09-01 19:00:00";
DateTime data2 = DateTime.ParseExact(dataExample, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

than it works fine. Could You tell what is wrong ?

Comment: I don't see where you're using `ParseExact` on the value pulled from your database. Where exactly are you receiving the error?

Comment: In this line: DateTime data2 = DateTime.ParseExact(Model.PelnaData, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); . "Model.PelnaData" is value from database.

Comment: Did you use your debugger and verify that `Model.PelnaData` is what you expect it to be?

Comment: Yes. With value from database everything is fine :/

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to set a string on a DateTime field:

```
terminarz.PelnaData = rdr["formatData3"].ToString();
```

The code line where you show the conversion is not inside your `while` loop, and [it works](http://csharppad.com/gist/e80a555ac21ca4f4fd06) just fine.

Try replacing the line above with:

```
terminarz.PelnaData = DateTime.ParseExact(rdr["formatData3"].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If it still fails, debug and check the actual value of `rdr["formatData3"]`.

Comment: I'am receiving error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTime' to 'string'" this time..

Comment: Here: "terminarz.PelnaData = DateTime.ParseExact(rdr["formatData3"].ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);"

Comment: What's `PelnaData` type?

Comment: PelnaData is a string data type, but after your comment i changed that into DateTime and now i will try with that.

Comment: If it's a string, it would work with the first code sample. If it's a DateTime, would work with the second one. Check the underlying property code (assuming `PelnaData` is property) or replace the expressions with constant values (`string.Empty` or `DateTime.Now`), just to help you find the real problem.

Comment: If I am replacing PelnaData by "DateTime data = DateTime.Now; string dataFormat = ""; dataFormat = data.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");"  than works fine. Really, I dont have no idea why received value from database wont work :/

Comment: Thank You for trying to help me, i found a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an international issue. Can you debug and see what "formatData3" is returning, is it in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss or any other format or is a valid month coming back?

That might be your issue.

Comment: I check that, received value from database was correct, but i found a solution: "string data = rdr["formatData3"].ToString(); DateTime data2; if (DateTime.TryParseExact(data, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out data2)); terminarz.PelnaData = data2;" resolved my problem.